# Getting error "Unable to find replication strategy class 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.simplestrategy" while creating keyspace

Tags: cassandra, datastax

I have installed "DataStax Distribution of Apache Cassandra 3.9.0".
After opening cassandra CQL shell i ran the below command

```
Create keyspace KeyspaceName
with replicaton{'class':'simplestrategy','replication_factor': 1}
```

But i am getting an error:

```
Unable to find replication strategy class 'org.apache.cassandra.locator.simplestrategy'
```

Comment: I got the answer. Actually i was giving the name as 'simplestrategy'..It should be 'SimpleStrategy'. Also the keyspace name should be quoted  i.e it should be "KeyspaceName".

Comment: Keep in mind you need "" around your keyspace name if you want it to take the case sensitivity into account.

Answer (score 8):

The replication strategy class name is case sensitive in CQL, the correct syntax for a SimpleStrategy with replication factor of 1 is:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE my_keyspace
WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra is case sensitive so you should use SimpleStrategy instead of simplestrategy and no spaces in between are appreciated.